# redux dispatch does not work

Tags: redux, dispatch

I am a redux beginner, everything is confusing for me right now. I am trying to create a store and dispatch a new value to the store, but it does not work, can someone help? thanks

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import uuid from 'uuid';

const state={
    id:0,
    numbers:[]
}

const randomNumber=()=>{...}

//reducer

const reducer=(state={},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_NUMBER':
        const newNumber={id:state.id+1, number:randomNumber()}
        return {
            ...state,
            id:uuid(),
            numbers:[...state.numbers,newNumber]
        }
    }
}

//store
const store=createStore(reducer)
store.subscribe(()=>{const state=store.getState})
console.log('new state should update, but it does not: ', state)

const addNumber =()=>({type: 'ADD_NUMBER'})

//dispatch
store.dispatch(addNumber())
```

this is my error [image]

Comment: Can you provide some more details on how it doesn't work? Do you get any errors, if yes what are they. If you don't get errors, did you check if the reducer is being called? or does nothing happens at all?

Comment: yes I got an error, I updated my question with the error, please take a look, I used console.log on state, but I delete it on my question to make my code shorter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is in this line,

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
```

Note that you have initialized your state to an empty object `{}`. So when you try to spread the `state.numbers` you are getting this error because `numbers` is not defined in the initial state.

```
return {
   ...state,
   id:uuid(),
   numbers:[...state.numbers,newNumber]
}
```

A minimal example that reproduces your issue,

```js
const bad = (state = {}) => {
  return {
    numbers:[...state.numbers]
  }
}

bad();
```

To fix this you'll need to initialize your state with the default values,

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    id:0,
    numbers:[]
}


//reducer
const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

// Rest of the code
```

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    id:0,
    numbers:[]
}
 
const good = (state = INITIAL_STATE) => {
  return {
    numbers:[...state.numbers]
  }
}

console.log(good());
```